html <table> <tr> element is not starting a new row
Fairly straightforward 2 column html <table>,  I thought:
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Fans</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          Supply air
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
        {#if Object.entries(supply_air_fan).length}
          {supply_air_fan.name}<br>{supply_air_fan.value}
        {/if}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          Exhaust air
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
        {#if Object.entries(exhaust_air_fan).length}
          {exhaust_air_fan.name}<br>{exhaust_air_fan.value}
        {/if}
        </td>
        <!--<td rowspan="2">
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
        </td>-->
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

So a row of headers, followed by two rows of data.
But, this is the output:

The table has "grown" to be 4 columns (well 3 header columns), with row 2 placed adjacent row 1
I guess I'm doing something wrong, or maybe <table> element is not the way forward for what I want to show?
(This is using bootstrap and svelte, I've tried without bootstrap, same results)

It's because of the rowspan="2" in the first row. Each of that would "add an extra column (but merged cell with the previous row)" which affects the next row, so the last row effectively has 4 columns (2 from the td inside the last tr, 2 from the previous one).

because all  td on all tr a  have   rowspan="2", so all the row have the same height.

Remove rowspan from all rows, that will fix it, using rowspan="2" means this td should take up 2 rows.

Yes, now I get it, thank you, it seems obvious now you point it out to me :) hmm, I'll ahve to find another way
